# Accessing base64 encoded data from Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, canvas, base64, raphael

I have some code that allows a user to annotate/draw on an image.  Then there's a save button that sends the image with the annotations to the server as a base64 encoded string.  I need to be able to "access" that data and basically save the edited image back to the server.

Button code:

```
<input id="clickMe" value="Save Image" onclick="ExportOpenImage();" type="button">
```

The function that is called:

```
function ExportOpenImage(){
  window.open(sp.exportAsCanvas().toDataURL('image/png') )
}
```

So, my question is, how can I pass the `base64 encoded` string to the server for processing instead of sending it to the browser for display?

I'm using Raphael and canvas in this.  If you need more of the code, please let me know.

Comment: POST it to the server with ajax.

Comment: [This post: http://www.nickdesteffen.com/blog/file-uploading-over-ajax-using-html5](http://www.nickdesteffen.com/blog/file-uploading-over-ajax-using-html5).

Comment: I'm terrible at javascript and I really don't understand both comments so far.